# AS3 Inheritance

Tags: actionscript-3, inheritance

When 'SubClass' extends 'SuperClass', when it inherit its methods and properties, it creates methods and properties that distinguishes from the 'SuperClass'?

Or if I create an instance of 'SubClass' and I try to modify a property, that was inherited from 'SuperClass', am I modificating the super class property also?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

```
package {

    public class SubClass extends SuperClass {

        public function SubClass() {
            trace('superclass value n='+superClass.n+'\n');
            trace('subclass changes inherited n'+'\n');
            n = 3;
            trace('subclass value n='+n+'\n');
            trace('superclass value n='+superClass.n+'\n');
        } 
    } 
}
```

Returns me:

```
superclass value n=-1;
subclass changes inherited n;
subclass value n=3;
superclass value n=3;
```

Comment: Where does `superClass` come from?  Is it an instance of SuperClass?  Is `n` a static variable of SuperClass?  That can't possibly be your current code and be working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will explain it in short.

We have two classes - Subclass and SuperClass.

SuperClass have four methods:

- private function methodPrivate():void;
- protected function methodProtected():void;
- public function methodPublic():void;
- internal function methodInternal():void;

From the Subclass you:

1. Cannot access methodPrivate():void;
2. Can access methodProtected():void; but just like your private method, it means, you cannot access it from outside of Subclass.
3. Can access methodPublic():void; and everything can access if from outside of Subclass also.
4. methodInternal():void; is available for classes from the package of SuperClass.

You can however override these methods. Overriding doesn't change a methods of SuperClass but change them only in SubClass.

```
override public function methodPublic() : void {
    // your additional code
    super.methodPublic(); // eventually calling the same method of SuperClass, you can pass arguments to it also
}
```

As you know, your SuperClass can also have variables, that also can be public, protected, private or internal. You cannot override them, but you can do this with getters or setters however.

You can access variables that are created as public or protected by using a word "super" like this: super.someVariable .

So everything is up to you, if you want to create a different variables of the same name in SuperClass and SubClass, just declare one as private in SuperClass. If you want to have one variable that SuperClass and SubClass both can access - just declare it as protected or public.

Hope that was clear.

Comment: Thanks, added it to complete summary.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a blank SubClass the extends SuperClass, you are creating a new class that provides the same interface (with the same implementation) to the parent class.

That is to say, if your parent class contains a method `doSomething`, your SubClass, without ever actually writing it, will have the `doSomething` method available as well.  The one caveat to this is if the method is marked `private`, in which case the inheriting class, SubClass, will not have access.

```
package {

    public class SuperClass {

        public function SuperClass():void {
            self.doSomething();
        }

        public function doSomething():void {
            trace("doing something");
        }
}


package {

    import SuperClass;

    public class SubClass extends SuperClass {

        public function SubClass():void {}
    }
}
```

Once you have this relationship established, you can decide whether calling `doSomething` on an instance of SubClass will behave differently than the default implementation, defined in SuperClass.  If you want the same behavior, you leave it as is.  If you want different behavior, then you override the parent class' method, using the keyword `override`.

```
package {

    import SuperClass;

    public class SubClass extends SuperClass {

        public function SubClass():void {}

        override public function doSomething():void {
            trace("doing another thing instead");
        }
    }
}
```

Now something that calls `doSomething` on an instance of SubClass will get modified behavior.  But the default implementation has not been touched.  Instanced of SuperClass are not modified by this overriding of a method.  Only instances of SubClass will be affected.

This is the same case for properties.

There is one exception to this, and that is static properties.  A static property is a property of the class, not of an instance of the class.  Static properties are not inherited.  A static property looks like this:

```
package {

    public class SuperClass {

        public static var i:int = 0;

        public function SuperClass():void {
        }

        public function doSomething():void {
            trace("doing something");
        }
}
```

The SubClass class will not have a reference to a static property i.  However, a SubClass instance can change the static value of the SuperClass.  As an example:

```
package {

    import SuperClass;

    public class SubClass extends SuperClass {

        public function SubClass():void {}

        override public function doSomething():void {
            trace("changing something in SuperClass");
            SuperClass.i = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the SuperClass's static variable `i` has a value of 1, instead of 0.  In this way a SubClass has the potential (although it is the same potential any code has with the right access privileges) to change the properties of SuperClass.

I hope this helps.

Comment: So a property inherited distinguishes from its superclass? I mean, if I modify 'p', inherited, on subclass, I´m not modifying superclass 'p'?

Comment: package 
{

 public class SubClass extends SuperClass
 {

  public function SubClass()
  {
   trace('superclass value n='+superClass.n+'\n');
   trace('subclass changes inherited n'+'\n');
   n = 3;
   trace('subclass value n='+n+'\n');
   trace('superclass value n='+superClass.n+'\n');
  }

 }

}

Returns me:


superclass value n=-1;

subclass changes inherited n;

subclass value n=3;

superclass value n=3;